# How to get a different quote of the day with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am using the code below which I found here, but it always returns the same quote. I can see that data itself has more quotes, but not sure how to parse them out one at a time. Thank you.

```
import requests

url = "http://www.forbes.com/forbesapi/thought/uri.json?enrich=true&query=1&relatedlimit=5"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

quote=data['thought']['quote'].strip()
```

Returns: 
u'Teach self-denial and make its practice pleasure, and you can create for the world a destiny more sublime that ever issued from the brain of the wildest dreamer.'

type(data) returns a dict. Then data.keys() returns [u'thought']. data.items() returns a bunch of text. Why only one key, if are seemingly more than one quote inside? And why does data = response.json() return disc with type(data), rather than a json object?

Comment: *Here's some code I copied and pasted from SO. Can someone modify it for me to do something else?* is not really how this site works. We're not your personal programming team. Make some effort to change it yourself, and then if you run into difficulty you can ask a specific question about that problem. Start by looking at what the JSON in `data` contains.

Comment: A bit of an assumption there Ken, both on me not giving it a try, and Data being a Json. In fact, type(data) returns a dict. Then data.keys() returns [u'thought']. data.items() returns a bunch of text, and yes, I am not sure how to grab the next item, hence the question. Care to help?

Comment: No assumption. Your post specifically says *I found this code here, and now I need someone to change it for me to do something else*. It's in the first sentence. No effort is based on the fact that you show none of those efforts in your question, and as we can't see your screen from where we're sitting, if it's not in the post it doesn't exist, ergo *no effort*. And `data = response.json()`.

Comment: Alright, as per your recommendation, I've added more context to the question. Please consider providing some further guidance.

Comment: On your question 'Why does `data = response.json()` return a dictionary rather than a json object?` - read http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content. `response.json()` decodes json data to a Python dict, it doesn't return a json object.

Comment: got it, thank you!

Comment: @KenWhite. Hey, I think you downvote got me banned from asking questions on SO. Just wanted you to know that Ken.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps when you've gotten the privilege of asking again, you'll put more effort into finding a solution yourself and then asking better questions. (A single downvote didn't get you banned, which means you've posted several posts here that were downvoted or closed previously. You can't blame me for your failure to learn from past mistakes. Instead, pay attention and stop making those same mistakes. If you can't, then accept responsibility for your own actions instead of blaming others.)

Comment: You're right, I seem to have a negative 2 in all of my questions. And you're right again, in that you weren't the only, but were the last and seemingly malevolent down-voter. And please remember Ken, it is much easier to make a new account on SO than to learn how to judge people favorably. I hope you're not and/or will not be in the need of either. Take care Ken and thank you for the lesson.

Comment: There's no malevolence. I don't know you. I can only judge the quality of your posts here. And please remember that those new accounts can also be closed as quickly as this one was, so it's only a benefit to create a new account if you conduct yourself differently with that new account. If you repeat the same poor behavior, that new account will be closed as well. And thanks for your concern for my account, but it seems to be doing OK so far.

Comment: Yeah.. whatever. At least this story will make for a good laugh with buddies at work on Thursday night at the pub. And yes, I'll be sure to take more care around the SO posting guidelines with my new account. Alright, no hard feelings, signing out now...  peace Ken.

Comment: I hope you enjoy it. I'd look for a better class of friends who would encouage me to improve myself. Hope you have fun at the pub. Don't know how there could be hard feelings, as (again) I don't know you. Hopefully you (and your friends) will show more regard for the people who spend their time here trying to make this a useful resource rather than a *please do everything for me* site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your json file at http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and saw the structure of data. Once you understand the structure.

```
import requests

url = "http://www.forbes.com/forbesapi/thought/uri.json?enrich=true&query=1&relatedlimit=5"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

#print recent quote from Thought
print '*'*10
quote=data['thought']["quote"]
print quote

#print quotes from related authors
print '*'*10
quotes_of_related_authors = data['thought']['relatedAuthorThoughts']
for i in quotes_of_related_authors:
    print i.get('quote')


# print quotes from related theme thoughts
print '*'*10
quotes_of_related_theme_thoughts = data['thought']['relatedThemeThoughts']
for i in quotes_of_related_theme_thoughts:
    print i.get('quote')
```

Comment: Thank you. What does it mean you copied my file at that site? I tried, it said my format is not valid..

Comment: Thanks you. I see what you mean. If I press the format button, it clearly shows keys.. or json elements..